# Mysql tables crashing after each XAMPP restart

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPP version: 7.3.7
Operating system Windows 10

Each time when I restart XAMPP random mysql table crashes.

Video here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR_OTxmPIP4&feature=youtu.be

I've been having this problem for weeks and wasted many hours trying to prevent that from happening. This is happening on both of my PCs.

I have tried to repair it with a command I found "mysqlcheck -u root --databases mysql --auto-repair --use-frm" and it works, but each restart same thing happens.

I also tried restoring tables from backups. Same thing, it does it's job repairing it, but when I restart server another table gets corrupted.

My questions are:

- What can I do to fix it?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a proper way to exit mysql server?
- If this isn't my or my computer's fault what version of XAMPP is free from this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is solved in the latest XAMPP version. (**7.3.8**)